Looking for slideshow utility with custom/configurable randomisation
I'm looking for a way to provide custom/configurable randomisation to a slideshow tool like impressive or feh (something lightweight I can run automatically at startup). Basically I need to weight certain directories according to how many photos there are in each.
Like, if there are two directories and one contains 90 photos and the other contains only 10, the time spent in each directory should depend not only on how many photos there are in total but also on how many directories there are, so somewhere between 10-50% of the time you might be looking at one from the 10 and the remaining 50-90% of the time you might be looking at one from the 90, according to some custom logic/math, rather than simply having a 10/90 split. Essentially I want to set a lower limit on the bias toward any given directory but still maintain some semblance of the relative proportions of each.
I might be able to do this in some jury-rigged way, but maybe someone knows of a way to do it out of the box. Is there anything like this or that might accomplish something similar? Thanks!
Edit:
Following the great advice below I set up the following randomisation function, adding bias toward directories with more photos by adding a coefficient which multiplies against the standing probability to determine how much of it is freed. Then, rather than redistribute probabilities according to fixed amounts, I chose to do so according to the existing 'stakes' on the rest of it. The resulting dynamics are such that those with biases toward losing less tend preferentially to receive the freed probability and are better able to maintain their supply, simply for having more and thus attracting more of what is freed elsewhere, but not in such a way that would never yield to the other directories, which every once in a while come due in accordance with their own, comparatively weaker biases. (The result of the bias calculation is proportional to the percent contribution of a directory to the total number of photos, but normalised around the value for an equal share that would be obtained when all directories contribute equally, such that those above this threshold are represented somewhat less than they would be otherwise, and those below somewhat more.)
To the more crucial point, as to how to leverage this functionality with respect to the image/slideshow utility: It interacts with the directory containing the photos being actively used (feh, the only one I could figure out how to get to work (so not fbi) and update its view of the directory as files change (so not impressive)). There is an option to have a sequence of photos active at once, back from when I thought I'd be able to use impressive and get transitions working, but that doesn't seem likely anymore. All the directory and photo selection and the redistribution of probability happens in this python script, once for every image change in the slideshow (and is self-correcting to the system clock, with the hope feh doesn't lose or gain time somehow, so that the two won't eventually desync). I was hoping there might be a formal way to do this somehow, but I'm not sure there is. Anyway, it seems like it works. If anyone sees this and takes offence at the sight of my python or shell scripting don't hesitate to set me right, if you feel like it.
I have one more component I need to work out which is to have it execute automatically after startup and establishing a network connection, but that's not so relevant to the question I was asking. But at any rate here is everything so far:
# Slideshow

import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from random import random
import shutil
import time

src_dir = './photos/src'
active_dir = './photos/active'
active_photo_interval = 24

valid_exts = ['.' + e for e in ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']]

photos = [[f.path for f in os.scandir(d.path) if f.is_file and os.path.splitext(f.path)[-1] in valid_exts] for d in os.scandir(src_dir) if d.is_dir()]
photos = [p for p in photos if len(p)]
total_members = len(photos)
total_photos = sum(len(p) for p in photos)

members = [
    {
        'prob': [
            i/len(photos)
            , (i + 1)/len(photos)
        ]
        , 'bias': 1 - (len(photos[i])/total_photos - (len(photos[i])/total_photos - 1/total_members)*((total_members - 1)/total_members)**total_members)
        , 'photos': [
            {
                'prob': [
                    k/len(photos[i])
                    , (k + 1)/len(photos[i])
                ]
                , 'path': photos[i][k]
            } for k in range(0, len(photos[i]))
        ]
    } for i in range(0, len(photos))
]


def get_image():
    mrand = random()
    midx = next(i for i,m in enumerate(members) if m['prob'][0] <= mrand < m['prob'][1])
    member = members[midx]

    if len(members) > 1:
        freed_prob = (member['prob'][1] - member['prob'][0]) * member['bias']
        total_standing_prob = sum(m['prob'][1] - m['prob'][0] for i,m in enumerate(members) if i != midx)
        for i,m in enumerate(members):
            standing_prob = m['prob'][1] - m['prob'][0]
            prob_stake = standing_prob/total_standing_prob
            m['prob'][0] = 0 if i == 0 else members[i - 1]['prob'][1]
            m['prob'][1] = 1 if i + 1 == len(members) else m['prob'][0] + standing_prob + (freed_prob * prob_stake if i != midx else -freed_prob)


    photos = member['photos']
    prand = random()
    pidx = next(i for i,p in enumerate(photos) if p['prob'][0] <= prand < p['prob'][1])
    photo = photos[pidx]

    if len(photos) > 1:
        freed_prob = photo['prob'][1] - photo['prob'][0]
        share_freed_prob = freed_prob/(len(photos) - 1)
        for i,p in enumerate(photos):
            standing_prob = p['prob'][1] - p['prob'][0]
            p['prob'][0] = 0 if i == 0 else photos[i - 1]['prob'][1]
            p['prob'][1] = 1 if i + 1 == len(photos) else p['prob'][0] + standing_prob + (share_freed_prob if i != pidx else -freed_prob)
    
    return photo['path']


active_photos_max = 1
active_photos = []
if os.path.isdir(active_dir):
    active_photos = [f.path for f in os.scandir(active_dir) if f.is_file]
else:
    os.mkdir(active_dir)

time_next = datetime.now()
while True:
    time_next = time_next + timedelta(seconds=active_photo_interval)
    active_photos.insert(0, get_image())
    shutil.copy(active_photos[0], active_dir)

    old_photos = [os.path.join(active_dir, p.split('/')[-1]) for p in active_photos[active_photos_max:]]
    for p in old_photos: os.remove(p)
    active_photos = active_photos[:active_photos_max]

    while datetime.now() < time_next:
        time.sleep(1)


#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Main

SYNC_INTERVAL=$(( 24 * 60 * 60 ))

while true
do
    python ./slideshow.py &
    sleep $SYNC_INTERVAL
    kill $!
    bash ./sync.sh
done


#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Entry/startup

. ./set_vars.sh

bash ./sync.sh
bash ./main.sh &
sleep 2
feh -R 24 -D 24 -Z -F -Y $ACTIVE_DIR



As someone who's taught probability theory / combinatorics, I do have remarks on what you describe above (I think it's not well-thought through; at the very least, it's not described clearly).
However,

according to some custom logic/math,

and

but maybe someone knows of a way to do it out of the box.

Either it's custom or it's out of the box :-)
Seriously, I think what you describe is so custom that nobody else has had seen the need for it before, so you'll have to implement that yourself.
What you're describing is pretty hairy an algorithm, because "viewing sessions" aren't infinitely long. So, under a truly memory-less random sequence, some folder that shows up 10% of times might simply not show up in the first 200 slides – that'd be perfectly normal and you can calculate the probability of that.
It's also just as likely that the same picture gets picked twice as that two different pictures with identical probability get picked.
So, my guess is that you don't really want a random sequence, but one that at every "next" image makes a (random!) decision, but with probabilities constrained by slides that happened within a "memory length" (i.e., all the pictures before, or the last 100 pictures, or such.)
Such algorithms exist for music players' shuffle function (because what is really independently random is pretty different to what a listener thinks is "good" randomness; even the obvious "take all songs and permute them randomly" is pretty bad in practice, because people dislike not only the same song being played twice in a short while, but also two songs from the same album coming right after each other, but in reverse order, and a lot such things).
However, a good baseline algorithm to implement in C++, Python, Rust or any language of your choice that has efficient associative arrays (so, definitely not a shell-script):

read in all candidate file names (i.e., walk all directories to gather all files) and all directory names.
assign each of them a probability according to your specification. That probably means all files from the same directory get the same probability; do the same for all directories.
pick the a directory based by uniformly sampling the [0,1] interval. You typically just use arithmetic coding to do that (you just divide the interval [0,1] into subintervals corresponding to each directory, and each subinterval is as wide as the directory is probable).
after picking the directory, you adjust the directory probabilities: you probably want to do something like reducing the probability of your directory by some fixed percentage, and distribute the "freed" probability amongst the other directories, so that "staying long in the biggest directory" is less of a problem.
you do the same you did to choose the directory with the images in that directory: pick a number between 0 and 1, and and apply an arithmetic decoder to pick a picture, then update the probabilities of the pictures in that directory.
you push the picked picture to the end of your image queue
you go back and pick the next directory


Thanks! I hadn't considered updating the probabilities with each pick--that makes a lot of sense! I was planning to avoid showing duplicates until a directory is exhausted, but freeing and redistributing probability for both levels seems better. (Also I was planning to build a series of symlinks in a dedicated folder, generated ahead of each slideshow cycle, with a min runtime 1h (to hide any seams), and simply play these in order; although after reading this now I wonder if I couldn't just append these at the same rate as the photos change). Anyway, your advice is really helpful, thanks!

Oh just to clarify by out-of-the-box vs custom I only meant, if there's some parameter I can pass to an option to do this, great (unlikely, as you point out); but if there's a way to control it programmatically and feed it images per the randomisation logic, that would be ideal.
The only way I know to implement some kind of customisation logic is going to have to be in some way async to the execution of the slideshow command of the utility (hence the initial idea to build a 1h-long queue ahead of the call, and the maybe better idea to try to run them in tandem), but obviously neither's great.
